# Can't open shared library in Python only on one machine

Tags: python, bash, cython

I have `cythonized` `.pyx` file to and made `sec_cam.so` file. I'm importing this file to `camera_launcher.py` when I'm executing this file(functions inside).

It works on my `Linux MX` inside of my `virtualenv wrapper` but wont work on my Ubuntu's `virtualenv wrapper` - Btw. I have installed same packages on both machines. And I'm doing the  exactly same commands on both (see bellow).
This is how my Ubuntu looks like and how `error` occurs

```sh
(test) suomi@suomi-desktop:~/Downloads/cyt_cam$ ls -al
total 540
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root    4096 11月 25 09:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 suomi suomi   4096 11月 25 09:42 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 suomi suomi    206 11月 25 09:52 camera_launcher.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 suomi suomi   3905 11月 25 09:37 sec_cam.pyx
-rwxrwxrwx 1 suomi suomi 534992 11月 25 09:39 sec_cam.so

(test) suomi@suomi-desktop:~/Downloads/cyt_cam$ pwd
/home/suomi/Downloads/cyt_cam

(test) suomi@suomi-desktop:~/Downloads/cyt_cam$ which python
/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python

(test) suomi@suomi-desktop:~/Downloads/cyt_cam$ sudo /home/suomi/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python camera_launcher.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "camera_launcher.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sec_cam import check_disk, camera_capture
ImportError: /home/suomi/Downloads/cyt_cam/sec_cam.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm importing the package in `camera_launcher.py` like this

```py
from sec_cam import check_disk, camera_capture
```

This works on my `MX Linux`, but not on my `Ubuntu`. I think its not the case, but perhaps isn't it because I compiled the file on `MX`?

**UPDATE:**

My Ubuntu was another architecture (AARCH64) So I recompiled `.so` file there and it worked!

Comment: You can try `ldd sec_cam.so` to check if it can be loaded

Comment: thanks for the comment, I found the issue and updated my post